# When is an irreducible $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ representation of a cusped hyperbolic 3-manifold scheme reduced or smooth?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, character-varieties

Let $M$ be an orientable cusped hyperbolic 3-manifold. Let $\rho \in  \mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1(M),\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C}))$ be an irreducible representation.

> Is $\rho$ scheme reduced ?

What can prevent $\rho$ from being a smooth point of the representation variety ?

Comment: Perhaps contact Misha Kapovich (https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/) with this question?  He'll know, or know who to point you to.

Comment: In particular, see his answer to this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/123198/can-the-sl-2-character-variety-of-a-three-manifold-be-nonreduced/123259#123259

Comment: In the question I am interested in the representation itself not the character but in case of hyperbolic manifold with n cusps we have an analytic fibration $R^{\text{irr}}(M)\to X^{\text{irr}}(M)$ of the irreducible representation over the irreducible characters so is it possible that $\rho$ is not scheme reduced (resp. smooth) if $\chi_{\rho}$ is not scheme reduced (resp. smooth) ?

Comment: You should rewrite the question instead of reinterpreting the question in the comments. For the question you are now asking the answer is: $X^{irr}$ is smooth (reduced) at $[\rho]$ iff $Hom$ is smooth (reduced) at $\rho$. This has nothing to do with hyperbolicity.

Answer (score 4):

I am turning Misha's comment into an answer, so this is not left unanswered under this tag.

The current question is:

> Is it possible that irreducible $\rho$ is not smooth (reduced) if $\chi_\rho$ is not smooth (reduced)?

Here is Misha's answer (which I agree with):

> $\mathfrak{X}^{irr}(\pi_1(M), \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C}))$ is smooth (reduced) at $\chi_\rho$ if and only if $\mathrm{Hom}^{irr}(\pi_1(M),\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C}))$ is smooth (reduced) at $\rho$.

Here is a comment from me:

It is possible for singular points in $\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma,G)$ to be smooth in $\mathfrak{X}(\Gamma,G)=\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma, G)//G$.  Take for example a genus 2 surface group $\Gamma$ with $G=\mathrm{SU}(2)$, then $\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma, G)/G\cong\mathbb{CP}^3$ but there are singularities in the $\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma, G)$ (coming from reducible representations).  Worse, even for free groups there are Lie groups $G$ of arbitrarily large rank with the
property that $\mathfrak{X}(F_2,G)$ has smooth reducibles and singular irreducibles for a rank 2 free group $F_2$.  See [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4720) and [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.0272) for more information.

One should also read Misha's great answer to a related question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/123198/12218).

Tangentially related are the answers [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/26978/12218).